# jQuery multiple validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have here a form validation. I used this validation in multiple editing records in php. I have two textbox that comparing it's value. I tried to mix my validation script and comparing value script but isn't working properly.

This what I have now but I'm having problem with this when I tried to input lower value in n_quanity field the validation error message is not working and it allowed the form to submit. I want to display error in span not alert the message. Help please?

```
var textBox1 = $(".n_quantity");
var textBox2 = $(".pr_total");

    $('.qty').each(function(){ // use $.each for all project class
    qty = this.value;
    for (var i = 0,len=textBox1.length; i < len;i++) {
    if(qty == "") {
        $(this).next("span.val_qty").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else if (parseInt(textBox2[i].value) > parseInt(textBox1[i].value)) {
        $(this).next("span.val_qty").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).next("span.val_qty").html("");
    }
    }
    });
```

**And this is my full code**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
var validation_holder;

$("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function() {

var validation_holder = 0;
$('.qty').each(function(){ // use $.each for all project class
qty = this.value;
if(qty == "") {
    $(this).next("span.val_qty").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
} else {
    $(this).next("span.val_qty").html("");
}
});

        if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 

}); // jQuery End
</script>

<script>
$('#sbtBtn').on('click', function () {
    var textBox1 = $(".n_quantity");
    var textBox2 = $(".pr_total");
    for (var i = 0,len=textBox1.length; i < len;i++) {
        if (parseInt(textBox2[i].value) > parseInt(textBox1[i].value)) {
            alert('value is greater than quantity');
            return false;
        } else {}
    }
});
</script>

 <p> <label for="">PR Quantity</label> <input name="n_quantity[]" id="n_quantity" class="qty n_quantity" type="text"/><span class="val_qty"></span> </p>
 <p style="display:none;"><input id="pr_total" class="pr_total" type="text"></p>
```